# Why does Swift give me a compiler error when my convenience initializer runs self.init inside if an if-let statement?

Tags: swift

Here is a sample of code that I'd like to get compiling:

```
class Fruit {
    var name: String

    init(name: String, season: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init?(data: [String: String]) {
        if let name = data["name"], region = data["region"] {
            self.init(name: name, season: region)
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error is "Use of 'self' in delegating initializer before self.init is called"

If the initializer is failable, shouldn't I be able to have code paths that don't run any initializer? This code compiles if you add an else with an initializer:

```
convenience init?(data: [String: String]) {
    if let name = data["name"], region = data["region"] {
        self.init(name: name, season: region)
    } else {
        self.init(name: "test", season: "test")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is perhaps misleading. You must explicitly  return `nil` if the initialization fails, as stated in
the documentation ["Failable Initializers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224):

> You write `return nil` within a failable initializer to indicate a point
>   at which initialization failure can be triggered.

Which means in your case that you have to add an else case
if the optional binding fails:

```
convenience init?(data: [String: String]) {
    if let name = data["name"], region = data["region"] {
        self.init(name: name, season: region)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Alternatively with `guard`:

```
convenience init?(data: [String: String]) {
    guard let name = data["name"], region = data["region"] else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init(name: name, season: region)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have read the documentation more closely. It would have been nice if the compiler error described what you pointed out.